# CS50 Project 1 Help - Wiki Search w/ Django - Stuck on how to save a new page

Tags: python, html, django, cs50

So I am creating my Wiki Search Page with Django and everything is going fine so far. I am now stuck on how to create a new entry in my search encyclopedia. On my home bar the "Create new Page" link works fine and takes me to a new page where I can create a new entry. The problem is when I try and save the entry into my encyclopedia I get this message:

ValueError at /new/
The view encyclopedia.views.new didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

I think it is a problem in my views.py section but can't seem to figure it out. Here is my views.py

```
def new(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/new.html", {
            "create_form": CreateForm(),
            "search_form": SearchForm()
        })
    

    file_content = request.POST.get("content","")
    file_title = request.POST.get("title", "")

    if (len(file_content) == 0 or len(file_title) == 0):
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
                "message": "Bad Request",
                "description": "Title and content cannot be empty",
                "status": 400
            }) 

    if util.get_entry(file_title):
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
                "message": "Bad Request",
                "description": "This page already exists",
                "status": 400
            })
```

Everything with the page works fine. I get the correct error when trying to save the page without any entry. The problem is it just won't save a new entry when I try and add text.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to create an object based on the transferred data, use `POST`, not `GET`.

```
def new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        create_form = CreateForm(request.POST)
        if create_form.is_valid():
            create_form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        create_form = CreateForm()

    return render(request, 'encyclopedia/new.html', {'create_form': create_form, 'search_form': search_form})
```

I think you could improve a few more things. Realize field constraints using `models` or `forms`. In the case of a search engine, it will be optimal to use `GET`.

```
request.GET.get
```